# context for using `yield` keyword in python

Tags: python, yield

I have the following program to scrap data from a website. I want to improve the below code by using a generator with a yield instead of calling `generate_url` and `call_me` multiple times sequentially. The purpose of this exersise is to properly understand `yield` and the context in which it can be used.

```
import requests                                                                                                                                                                                              
import shutil

start_date='03-03-1997'
end_date='10-04-2015'
yf_base_url ='http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5E'
index_list = ['BSESN','NSEI']

def generate_url(index, start_date, end_date):
    s_day = start_date.split('-')[0] 
    s_month = start_date.split('-')[1]
    s_year = start_date.split('-')[2]

    e_day = end_date.split('-')[0] 
    e_month = end_date.split('-')[1]
    e_year = end_date.split('-')[2]
    if (index == 'BSESN') or (index == 'NSEI'):
        url = yf_base_url + index + '&a={}&b={}&c={}&d={}&e={}&f={}'.format(s_day,s_month,s_year,e_day,e_month,e_year)
        return url 

def callme(url,index):
    print('URL {}'.format(url))
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False,stream=True)
    if r.status_code!=200:
        print "Failure!!"
        exit()
    else:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        with open(index + "file.csv", 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        print "Success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = generate_url(index_list[0],start_date,end_date)
    callme(url,index_list[0])
    url = generate_url(index_list[1],start_date,end_date)
    callme(url,index_list[1])
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: @user2357112 - on how to use yield in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options. You could use yield to iterate over URL's. Or over request objects.

If your `index_list` were long, I would suggest yielding URLs.
Because then you could use `multiprocessing.Pool` to map a function that does a request and saves the output over these URLs. That would execute them in parallel, potentially making it a lot faster (assuming that you have enough network bandwidth, and that yahoo finance doesn't throttle connections).

```
yf ='http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5E'
    '{}&a={}&b={}&c={}&d={}&e={}&f={}'
index_list = ['BSESN','NSEI'] 

def genurl(symbols, start_date, end_date):
    # assemble the URLs
    s_day, s_month, s_year = start_date.split('-')
    e_day, e_month, e_year = end_date.split('-')
    for s in symbols:
        url = yf.format(s, s_day,s_month,s_year,e_day,e_month,e_year)
        yield url

def download(url):
    # Do the request, save the file

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
rv = p.map(download, genurl(index_list, '03-03-1997', '10-04-2015'))
```

Comment: what is symbols above? I think index_list should be defined as symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really clears my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to know is how to change the code so that you can replace the last part by

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   for url in generate_url(index_list,start_date,end_date):
       callme(url,index)
```

If this is correct, you need to change `generate_url`, but not `callme`.  Changing `generate_url` is rather mechanical.  Make the first parameter `index_list` instead of `index`, wrap the function body in a `for index in index_list` loop, and change `return url` to `yield url`.

You don't need to change `callme` because you never want to say something like `for call in callme(...)`.  You won't do anything with it but a normal function call.